# Linq Count with Condition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I want to provide 2 condition's in the COUNT clause for checking ROLE & USERID.

Here is my code :-

```
var recordCount = ctx.Cases.Count();
```

How to give Where condition in Count()?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just add a predicate to your `Count()` expression (and don't forget to include `System.Linq`):

```
var recordCount = ctx.Cases.Count(a => a.Role == "admin");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var recordCount = ctx.Cases.Count(a => a.Role == "admin" && a.Userid="userid");
```

Answer (score 4):

First give Where and then count.

```
ctx.Cases.Where(c => your condition).Count();
```